# WaitGroup is reused before previous Wait has returned in multiple go routines

Tags: go

I have a go program with multiple goroutines. I am experiencing this error and I can't figure out why. This is my code logic:

**main.go**

```
for {
   ...
   go funcFile2()
}
```

Where funcFile2 is defined in File2.go and is called multiple times in a sort of loop

**File2.go**

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func func1(){
    defer wg.Done()
    return
}
func func2(){
    defer wg.Done()
    return
}
func func3(){
    defer wg.Done()
    return
}

func funcFile2(){
wg.Add(3)
go func1()
go func2()
go func3()
wg.Wait()
}
```

GO Version: go1.12.7

How can I solve?

Comment: The example code does not demonstrate the stated issue. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing what is actually causing your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If funcfile2() is called from multiple goroutines, then they are all sharing the same WaitGroup wg, which is valid. You get this error because in one of the goroutines wg.Wait() is called, and then in another goroutine wg.Add(3) is called, which is not valid. You cannot add more to a waitgroup once it starts waiting.

You have to have a separate waitgroup for each goroutine that calls funcfile2(). If this is in a for-loop, you can do something like:

```
for {
   wg:=sync.WaitGroup{}
   go funcfile2(&wg)
}
```

That way each goroutine calling funcfile2 will use its own waitgroup. Of course, funcfile2 has to pass the same waitgroup to the goroutines it creates.

Comment: This fixed my issue! Thanks

Comment: `WaitGroup`s *can* be shared among multiple go-routines. However the `WaitGroup` concept spans a particular _task_. Since there are multiple _tasks_, then as this answer shows, one needs individual `WaitGroup`s for each task.

Comment: There is no inherent requirement to have one WG per task. You can use it in any way that suits the purpose.

Comment: @Adrian sure it's just a counter - a counter that cannot go below zero. But its very name suggests it "wait" for a "group" (of sub-tasks) which represents a bigger _task_.

Comment: It's very name suggests it "waits" for a "group" - "task" isn't in there.  [The documentation clearly states](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) "A WaitGroup waits for a collection of goroutines to finish". The things it's waiting for agroup of are, specifically, goroutines. "Task" is a notion that you might have found helpful, but it has nothing to do with WaitGroups.

Comment: @Adrian I'll offer an example: I recently had a crawler of X go-routine workers that work on recursive task. To track when the task was complete, I used a `WaitGroup`: Add(1) for each recursive step; Done() when complete. The X go-routines never finish (they sit for any future next tasks) - but I can signal that the recursive-task has complete to the caller by waiting on this "recursive" WaitGroup.

Comment: Sounds like you should have just used channels. Regardless, the statement "However the WaitGroup concept spans a particular task. Since there are multiple tasks, then as this answer shows, one needs individual WaitGroups for each task" is not objectively true; it may be your personal rule of thumb, but it has nothing to do with how WaitGroups are intended to be used.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the accepted answer, you *can* call `Add(1)` after another thread has already called `Wait()`, as long as the total wait group count is > 0 when `Add(1)` is called.

from https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup.Add

> Note that calls with a positive delta that occur when the counter is
> zero must happen before a Wait.

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    WG := sync.WaitGroup{}
    WG.Add(1)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 4)
        fmt.Println("Adding while also waiting")
        WG.Add(1)
        WG.Done()
        WG.Done()
        // WG.Add(1)
    }()
    fmt.Println("Waiting")
    WG.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Returning")
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/cIBeZvyngyn

stdout

```
Waiting
Adding while also waiting
Returning
```

Now, if you were to uncomment the second `WG.Add(1)` line, you'll see the following runtime error

```
panic: sync: WaitGroup is reused before previous Wait has returned
```

After the second `Done()` is called, the wait group counter is 0, and `Wait()` has already been called by this point. So any `Add(1)` operation is not allowed during this moment in time.